# Delete specific object in array element in document and save mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to remove an object from my array. First, I want to find the customer by their ID, and then within the customer model in the array of carts, I want to delete one of the items based on the ID.

This is carts array in customer model :

```
   carts: [
      {
        items: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Cart",
        },
        amount: { type: Number, default: 1 },
      },
    ],
```

And this is delete Controller :

```
//delete bag item
export const deleteCartItemCtrl = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { userId, id } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = Customers.updateOne(
      { _id: userId },
      {
        $pull: {
          carts: { items: [{ _id: id }] },
        },
      }
    );
    res.json({
      status: "success",
      message: "cartItem delete successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error),
      res.status(500).json({
        status: "error",
        message: "An error occurred while cart item delete",
      });
  }
});
```

I used "pull", but the item I want to delete isn't getting removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your schema you have an array of `carts` objects, each with a property of `items` that is of type `ObjectId`. You can use [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndUpdate()), which you will need to `await`, and then `$pull` the object form the array like so:

```js
const user = await Customers.findByIdAndUpdate(userId,
   {
      $pull: {
         carts: {
            items: id
         },
      }
   },
   { new : true }
);
```

Comment: @amirzakipour You're welcome. If you found the answer useful please consider [marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this:

```
const result = await Customers.updateOne(
    {_id: userId},
    {
        $pull: {
            carts: { items: id }
        }
    })
```

This should remove the item from the carts array.

Comment: The `updateOne` method does not return the user document, it returns an object containing properties such as `acknowledged` or `modifiedCount`. The `user` variable will not hold the user data.

Comment: You're welcome. Just incase you try to access any of the user properties.